# Could not resolve org.springframework.bo

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

The following exception message appears every time I build: idea Build Output：

```java
Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies...
```

build.gradle.kts

```java
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { setUrl("https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone") }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.4.13")
    }
}

plugins {
    id("java")
}

group = "com.xhz"
version = 11

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "java")
    apply(plugin = "org.springframework.boot")
    apply(plugin = "io.spring.dependency-management")
}
```

settings.gradle.kts

```java
rootProject.name = "meihu"
include("user")
include("common")
```

My environment

Idea 2021.3

Gradle 7.4.2

JDK 11.14

Windows 10 19044 x64

I am new to Gradle. What can I try next?

Comment: do not mix 2 styles of plugins

Comment: Hello, teacher! Could you please show me an example. I don't understand what it means? ? ? thank you very much!
teacher! Could you please give a code example or point out where is the error in the current code? thank you very much!

Comment: I meant do not use 2 styles of plugin declaration - just `plugins {
    id('java')
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.6.7"
}`

Comment: build.gradle is OK: https://i.imgur.com/CzhaM3m.png
Try re-importing Gradle project, and File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart.